# locking up a linux box on a foreign network

Tags: linux, security, linux-networking

I have an app that runs on a Linux server and is accessed via each user's web browser.  My app contains proprietary code that I need to keep secure.  I want to install the app in a client's private network for their staff to use, but I would need to make sure that they are not able to access the app's code.  I only want them to be able to use their web browsers to interact with the app as clients of a web app.

I have not administered a Linux server before.  I would buy my own server box, install Linux on it, then install my app and place my server box in my client's local network.

Is there some way that I can configure the Linux box so that I am the only person who can access the machine with anything other than a web browser limited to specific url patterns?

Comment: Note that once they have physical access you're already pwned.

Comment: @AndréDaniel What attack vectors are you suggesting?  And how do I protect against them?  Let's say they want to pop out the hard-drive and extract the image of my code.  How do I protect against that or other physical attacks?

Comment: You can use full disk encryption and keep the key in the TPM like BitLocker, though I'm not sure if Linux has any support for that (TrustedGRUB seems abandoned)... but even then, a cold boot attack is possible. The best solution is to host the server yourself, and have the company set up a VPN tunnel to your network to access the app.

Comment: The more common approach nowadays is not to supply a physical box (with all the problems of providing hardware support, warranty correct power cords, sliding rails that fit in square or round holed support posts etc)  but a virtual appliance. With some simple tricks you can make those quite secure against the common thief.

Comment: the question woudl be: whether you want to just encrypt the source code for the app. You can't encrypt the binary ( I don't know of any kernel hook that performs decryption on demand).... so, in this case, just encrypt the source code before you ship and that's it.

Comment: @MichaelMartinez Thank you for your suggestion.  But my app is written in Java using the Spring framework and running on tomcat server.  I am under the impression that I cannot encrypt a war file.  I have read about tools to obfuscate java code, but can I actually encrypt it?

Comment: @CodeMed. I don't know of any kernel hook that performs decryption on the fly. Which means you can't encrypt code that is meant to be executed on the host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, if someone wants to break this badly enough, they can -- having access to the hardware makes this more feasible.   That said, you can make it very difficult.  For example:

1. Create a basic Linux setup.  That system should be locked down to allow web access only
   for the clients, but needs to allow access to you - for example use SSH and public/private
   keys, as well as making sure the appropriate port is allowed through their firewall from
   your network.  The basic system should DO NOTHING MORE THEN BOOT, ALLOW YOU ACCESS AND
   NOTIFY YOU IF THE SERVER RESTARTS. You need to keep a large amount of space free for 
   part 2.
2. Create a LUKS volume, and host your code and application on there.   When the system
   restarts, log in via SSH, mount the LUKS volume, start the applications residing there
   and log out.

This does not prevent cold boot attacks to get the contents of memory, or is someone is able to hijack the memory in the machine and read it while it's on (remember they have physical access), but short of that it would be pretty difficult for someone to compromise it.

Comment: +1 and thank you for taking the time to help me better understand this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The Linux, by its nature, is built to support multi-level and remote access. In your case, securing the application is easy, since it runs on Web. There are several options that can enable you to access the server remotely. The most popular way of administering a remote server is through SSH. Since you are new to server management, you might find Webmin (webmin.com) as an interesting tool, which can help you through server management process. Additionally (if you prefer configuring your server through GUI), you can use any of the Remote Desktop options like rdesktop or VNC.

The point you need to understand is that your code residing on the server and being served by a web server is considered to be secure by the linux's native authentication system. Nobody can have access to your code unless you provide them with credentials.

--Update --
If you want to block everything from being accessed through network except for the web port, then use the following command:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP iptables -A 
INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

This firewall rule will block incoming connection to any service except for web requests. As for physical security, the default linux authentication will be suficient, although experienced linux users can bypass the authentication by rebooting the system on "runlevel 1"

I hope it helps,
Hex

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look into this.  You answer seems to assume that my app would be on a remote server.  This is not correct.  My app would be in my client's place of business in a computer that I would own.  I would plug my server/computer into their network, and their users would access it like any other computer on their network, except that I would want to limit their access to that done via a web browser as users of my app.  I would want to make sure they cannot somehow access the Linux equivalent of the windows desktop of the machine and hunt for code etc.

Comment: Please check the update on my answer.

Comment: +1 and thank you for taking the time to help me better understand this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is easy to implement, and in fact installing Linux out of the box there won't be any way for users to logon unless you specifically create accounts and give them access. In a nutshell, here's what you do:

1. install the Os, install the apps
2. Create a local user account for yourself
3. Install/activate your ssh server and configure it so that it allows only your user account to login; additionally configure it to restrict the ip address/range where you can login from
4. configure Linux firewall (iptables)
5. make sure the web server does not have read-access to the code files

EDIT: as per davidgo's comment:

6. you'll need to encrypt the source code so that they can't examine it.

Comment: This doesn't work as the user can simply boot from a USB key or take the drives out and pull the data.  You need to ensure the data is stored encrypted as well.

Comment: ah yes, I missed the part where he said it's on the user's private network.... in this case, yes you're right, you would have to encrypt the source code.

Comment: +1 and thank you for taking the time to help me better understand this problem.